# Light intensity

Tags: java, android

This following service detects light intensity and writes its value in a file on every sensor change event. What i want is that whenever this service is called, it should write the value of sensor at that time. Not on sensor change.

**My Code Below :**

```
public class LightIntensity extends Service {

    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private SensorEventListener mEventListenerLight;
    private float lastLightValue;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

        mEventListenerLight = new SensorEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                float[] values = event.values;
                lastLightValue = values[0];
                createLog();

            }
            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent,int startId) {
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mEventListenerLight, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mEventListenerLight);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void createLog() {

        String data = String.valueOf(lastLightValue);

        String file_name = "light_log";
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(file_name, MODE_APPEND);
            fos.write(data.getBytes());
            fos.close();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File not found :" + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IO exception : " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's your question? Where do you struggle? What did you try?

Comment: right now (above), the log is created when the sensor is changed, I want to create log when the service starts as i do not want the value of light at every change in light intensity, but i want to read the value when the service starts.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to directly query a `Sensor` on-demand in Android.
However, you could accomplish this using a two class approach.

Create a singleton `LightManager` that registers for the `OnChange` listener, as above. On every change, store the current light value in a variable called `lastLightValue`.

Instead of your `LightIntensity` class registering for `Sensor` changes, it would simply access `LightManager.getInstance().lastLightValue`.